Seeking Information on Theravada Bhikkhuni Monasteries in Canada, USA, and New Zealand
I am a student from the UK interested in pursuing PhD research focused on Bhikkhuni ordination within Theravada Buddhism. As part of my research, I am seeking information on Theravada Bhikkhuni monasteries located in Canada, the USA, and New Zealand, where fully ordained Bhikkhunis reside and practice.
I would greatly appreciate any recommendations or resources regarding these monasteries. I am particularly interested in gaining firsthand experience with Bhikkhunis to enrich my research and inform my future academic pursuits.

You might get other answers here -- https://discourse.suttacentral.net/ -- A problem for this site, perhaps that one too, is that this is a "Question and Answer" site and you're not asking a question.

Ask the same question on the discussion forum of the Sutta Central website (the proprietors carried out the first modern Theravāda bhikkhuni ordinations).
And surely your first choice is to approach said monasteries directly? Why muck around with random internet questions when you can simply look them up and contact them directly?
See, e.g. https://www.dhammawiki.com/index.php/Category:Bhikkhuni_monasteries
